# How is data width determined for load/store instructions in Rocket Core?

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip, instruction-encoding

I'm working on a project where we need to modify a Rocket-chip core with new instructions.
We're wondering: how does data width for load/store instructions is determined ?

- For instance, LB/LH/LU have the same parameters set https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/rocket/IDecode.scala#L88-L90
- LB/LH/LU have different encoding (for instance https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/rocket/Instructions.scala#L277).

I assume the instruction decoder will determine the data width thanks to the `funct3` field but I do not see where this operation is performed in the Rocket decoder.

Any idea?

---

Looking at the Github repository (links above) + grep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by myself.

- The instruction in binary format is read here: https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/v1.6/src/main/scala/rocket/RocketCore.scala#L470
- https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/v1.6/src/main/scala/rocket/RocketCore.scala#L470. Bits 13 and 12 of the instruction are equal to the lowest bits of the `func3` field which are different for each load width.
- The highest bit of the `func3` field is needed for unsigned operations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).